# Computer run into Error 2738 while installation

Tags: windows, windows-installer, vbscript, setup

**Enviroment**

Windows 10 Home
64-Bit

**Problem**

I try to run the installation of the ne ZOOM R16 audio interface driver.
If I start the installation, I run into this error:

> R_16_R24 Driver Installation Information
>
> ---
>
> Error 2738.Could not access VBscript run time for custom action **.**

[image]

I try the whole day to fix this error. But without success.

This issues I tried:

- DISM.exe
- SFC
- `regsvr32 \u vbscript.dll` and `regsvr32 vbscript.dll`
  (as admin and not as admin)
- use the CCleaner tool to clean the registry an temp. files
- I also try to find an "easy fix" from Microsoft but also without success

I reboot my computer after each try, without success.
What could be the trigger of this error and how can i fix it

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Hang" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1002</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>101</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-09-17T16:38:32.707199100Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>43856</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>Me-PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>setup.exe</Data> 
  <Data>2.1.0.9</Data> 
  <Data>fb4</Data> 
  <Data>01d32fd35256ea34</Data> 
  <Data>4294967295</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Users\Me\Downloads\E_ R16_R24_Driver_win_v2.1.0_1\E_ R16_R24_Driver_win_v2.1.0\setup.exe</Data> 
  <Data>d0dc865c-037e-48c0-81e3-f33b70a66ae0</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Binary>54006F00700020006C006500760065006C002000770069006E0064006F0077002000690073002000690064006C00650000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

[image: Information of the driver setup.exe]

Comment: You appear to be trying to install a 64 bit program. Have you tried running `regsvr32 vbscript.dll` in the `%windir%\syswow64` directory?

Comment: You may also want to try disabling your antivirus program during the installation (at your own risk of course).

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you for your fast reply, Yes. I tried both. Without a success.

Answer (score 0):

No it works.
I run the steps from [this website](http://www.jakeludington.com/windows_7/20091115_error_2738_could_not_access_vbscript_run_time_for_custom_action.html).
It descripe one base of Windows7, but it works on Windows10 too.